# How to find webcam rotation angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a newbie in Unity. I want to find the rotation angle of the webcam. I tried some codes but it does not work.

I tried some codes but it does not work and gave errors or (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) result.

```
public WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
public Quaternion baseRotation;
void Update()
{
    webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
    int webcamAngle = webcamTexture.videoRotationAngle; //this one gave me error.
 }
```

I also tried

```
Quaternion webcamAngle = new Quaternion();
webcamAngle = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
Debug.Log(webcamAngle); //this gave me (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

I expect to get the rotation angle or value based on webcam movement.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you.

Comment: Does your camera hardware provide such a value? Where should Unity get the Camera rotation from? When dealing with e.g. VR Headsets they provide the camera movement and rotation through their API, Smartphones have their accelerators ... But I never heard of a WebCam providing transformation data... Otherwise did you call [`Application.RequestUserAuthorization`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestUserAuthorization.html) as the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-videoRotationAngle.html) suggests?

Comment: I tested that function and I got "Webcam found". I did not know that WebCam does not provide transformation data. Do you know any other way to get rotation value based on webcam movement because I just use Microsoft Lifecam HD-3000? Thank you.

Comment: Based on the specs of that camera, it does not appear to have an accelerometer or any other sensor to determine rotation, so I think you'll have to buy a camera with sensors and an API that supports rotational tracking data, if that's what you need.